# TortoiseGit occasionally is not able to reach git.exe

Tags: windows-10, git, tortoise-git

Occasionally when performing git operations with TortoiseGit I keep running into various failures randomly, wherein if I retry it once or twice afterward it will succeed in performing the same operation. This happens randomly across the board on pulls, pushes, commits, check-outs etc.

Going into the general settings, I can push a button to query the version where I assume it makes a call to git.exe to poll the version, and this random failure behavior is visible there as well.

This is on a workstation supplied by the company that I work in, so my user does not have explicit administrative access to it. (Worth noting is that on my personal computer at home I have never encountered such an issue.) So I was wondering if this could be due to some group policy which goes berzerk randomly or due to something else?

*Here's a small demo on how the issue looks from the general settings perspective:*
[image: demonstration]

Comment: Error  -1073741502 is error 0xC0000142 which is STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED. Do you have an anti virus running or something similar which could interfere here?

Answer (score 0):

Exit code `-1073741502` is in hex `0xC0000142, which
[Windows NTSTATUS values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx) shows means STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED which is:

> {DLL Initialization Failed} Initialization of the dynamic link library %hs failed. The process is terminating abnormally.

Unfortunately, your error message does not indicate the DLL that failed.

If I had to guess, I would think that the Git client version you have installed
is unsuitable for running your version of TortoiseGit.

I would suggest uninstalling both, then downloading and installing, in order:

- [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/)
- [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/)

If this does not help, please let me know your installed versions of both
products.